# $M/im(f)$ is Torsion

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a Principal ideal domain and $f:R^{n}\rightarrow M$, be an injective homomorphism where $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. I need to show that $M/im(f)$ is Torsion.

I know that since $f$ is injective then $ker(f)$ is trivial. Also that $im(f)$ is a submodule of $M$, therefore $M/im(f)$ is well defined since it is a quotient module. Do I have to use the existence of decomposition factors for $M$, and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't $f$ want to be rather *surjective*?

Comment: @Berci In that case, $M/im(f)=\{0\}$ would certainly be torsion :)

Comment: Ah, ok :) you're right. I was thinking about a less trivial proof for that case

Comment: @leonhardLeibniz have you checked the statement of the problem to make sure you copied it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Let $M$ be $R\times R$ and let $f:R\to M$ be given by $f(r)=(r,0)$.

Then $M/Im(f)\cong R$ is not torsion.